# Inverse Trigonometric Functions Advanced

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Suppose $α=\sin^{-1}(2x/1+x^2)$ when $-1≤x≤1$,
$β=\cos^{-1}((3\cos(y)-4\sin(y))/10)$ when $0≤y≤2π$ and
$ε=2\tan^{-1}(z^2-4z+5)$ when $z$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$.
If $α,β$ and $ε$ are interior angles of a triangle such that $(β+ε)$ is minimum then $x+\tan^-1(y)+z=(a-\sqrt{b})/c$ when $a,b,c$ belong to $\mathbb{N}$.
Find the least value of $\sqrt{a+b+c-2}$

My approach: I found out that the maximum value of $\alpha$ is $π/2$ so $x$ is $1$
The sum of remaining angles is $π/2$ so I tried a graphical approach and got $\alpha={π/2}$, $\beta={π/3}$, $ε={π/6}$

Comment: Instead of `\sin^-1` write `\sin^{-1}`, or better still `\arcsin`. Similarly for the other inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: How do you even know that $\alpha + \beta + \epsilon = \pi$? (As they are the interior angles of a triangle, that should be true)